# removing one letter except a compination

Tags: regex

Trying to remove all characters except from the compination of 'r d`. To be more clear some examples:

`a ball -> ball
r something -> something
d someone -> someone
r d something -> r d something
r something d -> something`

Till now I managed to remove the letters except from `r` or `d`, but this is not what i want. I want to keep only the compination(ex.4). I use this:

`\b(?!r|d)\w{1}\b`

Any idea who to do it?

*Edit*:The reg engine supports lookbehinds.

Comment: What's your regex engine? Does it support lookbehinds? Do you need to allow multiple spaces between `r` and `d`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may capture the `r d` combination and use a backreference in the replacement pattern to restore that combination, and remove all other matches:

```
\b(r d)\b|\b\w\b\s*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IuywbI/1) (replace with `$1` that will put the `r d` back into the result).

**Details**:

- `\b(r d)\b` - a "whole word" `r d`  that is captured into Group 1
- `|` - or
- `\b\w\b\s*`  - a single whole word consisting of 1 letter/digit/underscore (`\b\w\b`) and followed with 0+ whitespaces (`\s*`, just for removing the excessive whitespace, might not be necessary).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Is `\s*` same as ` +` ?

Comment: `\s` matches whitespace symbols (the set can vary between regex flavors) and a literal space only matches a regular space. In your regex101 link above, you replaced the match with an empty string, thus, you removed all the captured texts, too. [Use `$1` as a replacement string.](https://regex101.com/r/GU3skZ/2) See my answer: ***(replace with `$1` that will put the `r d` back into the result)***